# Indexing a list using values in another list (python)

Tags: python

Say I have a list of strings, `mylist`, from which I want to extract elements that satisfy a condition in a another list, `idx`:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']


idx = ['want','want','dont want','want']
```

What I want as output is:

```
['a','b','d']
```

which is a list of elements that I `'want'`

How can this by done?

Comment: `[mylist[i] for i,x in enumerate(idx) if x == 'want']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to stride through your two lists element-wise, then keep the elements from `mylist` if the corresponding element from `idx` equals `'want'`

```
>>> [i for i, j in zip(mylist, idx) if j == 'want']
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks Cory!